# activities perspective issue

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a sample plugin which needs to hide the java perspective. For that I used activities. The problems what happends is,it is hiding from the perspectives,but it is there still in the (recent opened perspectives). How can I hide it from there also? Following is my code.

```
  <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
  <activity
        id="com.example.activities.hideperspective"
        name="Hide Perspective">
  </activity>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="com.example.activities.hideperspective"
        isEqualityPattern="false"
        pattern="com.example.activities.hideperspective/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.JavaPerspective">
  </activityPatternBinding>
```

Is this the right way what I have implemented? One more thing, This hiding of perspective I am calling when I click a Button on the toolbar. That the that buttons location is also getting changed. some kind of refresh on the toolbar.

I have attached the screenshot as well.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The activityPatternBinding is plugin.id/perspective.id, where the plugin.id is the ID of the plugin that contributed the perspective, not com.example.activities.hideperspective.  Also, it does look like an equality pattern.

Also, activities will show something (like a perspective) if **any** activity that points to that perspective is enabled.  So setting one activity to `enabled=false` might not get rid of the perspective.

And finally, activities won't shut a perspective that is already open.  It just removes it from the "Open Perspective" dialog/shortcuts.

Comment: HI Paul, yes I made mistake. I suppose to enter PLUGINID\perspectiveid. I know it should PLUGINID\perspective id,still I made mistake.Anyway now it is working fine. Btw why we are using enabled false/true. I did not understand that part.could u please explain when will use enabled=false or enabled=true?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the notion that the activity is enabled or disabled, not specifically setting an attribute true or false.